# Sorting and dynamically allocation singly-linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, c-strings

My code works but only for small amount of data, like this:
* c d b a A C B D * input is -> ** a A b B c C d D  **

I need it for huge amount of data, like few MB of txt file.
My program has to read data from file, then sort them and save into another file.

That's my struct:

```
***


struct Word
    {
      char* word;
      struct Word* pNext;
    };

    typedef struct Word Word;
```

---

That's part of my main code:

---

```
Word* s_words = NULL;
    FILE* input_file = NULL;
    if(input_file != NULL){
      InsertWordsToStruct(&s_words, input_file);
      fclose(input_file);
    }
    else{
      ShowErrorUnknownFileName();
      RemoveWordList(&s_words);
      return 0;
    }
    bubbleSort(s_words);
```

---

My functions:

---

```
void AddElementToWord(Word** pH, char* word){
  Word* temp = *pH;
  int word_length = strlen(word);

  Word* new_item = (Word *)malloc(sizeof(Word));
  new_item->word = (char *)malloc((word_length+1)*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(new_item->word, word);
  new_item->pNext = NULL;

  if (*pH == NULL){
    *pH = new_item;
  }

  else{
    while(temp->pNext != NULL){
      temp = temp->pNext;
    }

    temp->pNext = new_item;
  }
}
void InsertWordsToStruct(Word** pH, FILE* filename){
  char one_line[8192];
  while(fgets(one_line, 8192, filename))
  {
    char* one_word = strtok(one_line, " \t\n\0");
    while(one_word != NULL)
    {
      if(IsLegitWord(one_word) == true)
      {
        char* copied = NULL;
        copied = (char *)malloc((strlen(one_word)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(copied, one_word);
        AddElementToWord(pH, copied);
        free(copied);
      }
      one_word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n\0");
    }
  }
} 

void RemoveWordList(Word** pH){
  Word* current = *pH;
  while (current != NULL){
      Word* next = current->pNext;
      free(current->word);
      free(current);
      current = next;
  }
  free(current);
  *pH = NULL;
}

char* MakeLowerCase(char* word)
{
  char* lower = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word)+1);
  strcpy(lower, word);
  int i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < strlen(lower); i++){
    lower[i] = tolower(lower[i]);
  }
  return lower;
}

void swap(Word* a, Word* b)
{
  char* word = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(a->word)+1);
  strcpy(word,a->word);
  strcpy(a->word,b->word);
  strcpy(b->word,word);
  free(word);
}

void bubbleSort(Word* start)
{
    int swapped = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Word* pointer = start;
    Word* previous = NULL;

    if (start == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        pointer = start;

        while (pointer->pNext != previous)
        {
            if (strcmp(MakeLowerCase(pointer->word), MakeLowerCase(pointer->pNext->word)) > 0)
            {
                swap(pointer, pointer->pNext);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            pointer = pointer->pNext;
        }
        previous = pointer;
    } while (swapped);
}
```

---

If you guys could help me I would be thankful. I can contact with someone to share whole project if it would help.

Comment: You could initially insert nodes in the sorting order. The function swap invokes undefined behavior for example due to this statement strcpy(a->word,b->word); because the size of the string a->word can be less than the size of the string b->word. As nodes have pointers to strings then there is no need to copy the strings themselves. You could swap just the pointers.

Comment: How can I swap the pointers? Sorry I'm new :v

Comment: For example void swap(Word* a, Word* b) { char *tmp = a->word; a->word = b->word; b->word = tmp; } But I think you need not to swap the strings but to swap the nodes themselves.

Comment: I will try in an hour and let u know

Comment: Ok, it helped but not complete. I rewrite your function and it worked, but for 10k words. For 250k it is processing for like 2 minutes and there is no result.Could we contact on Messenger or something? If u have a moment ofc

Comment: Nah, it won't help. That was just an accident :/ But If u have some time and want help I still invite you to messenger :D